# Minimal number of point from a regular grid in hypercubes?

Tags: combinatorics

Working on some probability problem, a combinatorial question arises :

Given $G$ a regular $N\times...\times N$ ($d$-times) grid over $[0,1]^{d}$ (for example for d=1, this is simply the collection of points : $0,\frac{1}{N},\frac{2}{N},...,\frac{N-1}{N},1$), taking any closed hypercube $H$ of side $h$ included in $[0,1]^{d}$, can we have a (sharp) lower bound on the number of point of $G$ lying in $H$ ?

At first glance I was convinced that this lower bounded by a constant times $(Nh)^{d}$ (for $h>>N$) but it seems not that obvious now.